# Dropbox api get previous file version preview url

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I need direct the user to a file with a particular rev number. Currently, I can only download the files of previous version but not a link. For example, for the current version file, I can create a shareable link and direct the user to view the document, but not work for files with previous versions. So is there a way to solve it? I am using the dropbox java library as well.

Comment: Is there a way to get the current preview URL displayed in IFrame ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do this that I can think of. You can download a particular rev of a file, or revert a file to a particular revision, but you can only share at the current rev. (And in fact, share links will always point at the latest version.)

The only workaround I can think of is to create a copy of the file at the desired rev, distinct from the original file, and link to that. You could either do this by downloading the desired rev, and then re-uploading it at a different path, or similarly by temporarily restoring the file to the desired rev and then making a copy of it, before restoring the original file back to current rev.